Issue with Bor on Polygon Full Node: "local keystore not used" Error
I’ve set up a PoS Polygon full node. Heimdall is running successfully, but I’m having an issue with Bor. I’ve added “personal” to the [jsonrpc.http] API in Bor config.toml like this:
port = 8545 host = "0.0.0.0" api = ["eth", "net", "web3", "txpool", "bor", "personal"]
However, I’m encountering an error in the logs that says: “local keystore not used.” ( I’ve created a keystore directory and set it’s path in config.toml. )
bor account new works fine, but "local keystore not used" appears when I try to create accounts via RPC and IPC.
Can anyone help me troubleshoot this? I’m happy to provide more information if needed.
Thanks!
Log Details :
WARN [06-22|05:16:48.815] Enabling deprecated personal namespace 
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: bor/v1.3.3/linux-amd64/go1.22.3
datadir: /var/lib/bor/data
modules: admin:1.0 bor:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0

To exit, press ctrl-d or type exit
> personal.newAccount
function github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/internal/jsre.MakeCallback.func1()
>  personal.newAccount("password")
GoError: Error: local keystore not used at InvalidResponse (web3.js:3143:16(29))
        at github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/internal/jsre.MakeCallback.func1 (native)
        at <eval>:1:20(3)

I've tried creating the directory manually and using flags directly to ensure the keystore is utilized to fix the error. I expected that by configuring these settings, I would be able to create accounts using personal.newAccount through IPC or RPC without encountering any issues.
Despite these efforts, the error persists, and I continue to see the message "local keystore not used" in the logs when attempting to create accounts via RPC.
